# Google Play Console, internal test releases send back analytics data from real devices, is it ok?

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-play, google-play-console

We have recently start to frequently use Google Play Console internal test to release our app to QA people before publishing. Seconds after every internal test release, we start receiving real-time analytics (GA and Fabric) for the new unreleased versions, from all over the world, by multiple real devices. Our QA team is too small to explain that, also the devices models does not match.

My question is, does Google run automatic tests on every Play Console release, also internal tests, on physical devices? Or is there something I should investigate better?

If Google does that, can I do something to avoid "fake" data, other than muting any analytics with build flags? I prefer to avoid it, since we usually "promote" internal tests to public releases when they are ok, directly from the Play Console without making a new build.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> does Google run automatic tests on every Play Console release, also internal tests, on physical devices?

They run automated tests, yes, see the quote at the bottom of my answer. No they don't use physical devices. They use emulated devices configured to represent real users, hence you see different locations.

> can I do something to avoid "fake" data, other than muting any analytics with build flags?

I'm not sure, since the point of these tests is to simulate real use. You can however tell google not to test your app this way, as you have pointed out in the comments. See "Disable pre-launch reports" in the console for more information.

[Pre launch reports](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7002270?hl=en)

> After you upload and publish a test APK or app bundle, test devices will automatically launch and crawl your app for several minutes. The crawl will perform basic actions every few seconds on your app, such as typing, tapping, and swiping.

Comment: I wasn't aware that they do it also for internal tests. I tried to search online, but I didn't found that page. Thanks. It looks like there's an option to "Disable pre-launch reports" in the console. Great, I'll hear colleagues and we'll see.

Comment: @lorenzo-s great. Included the disable option in the answer